# How to separate concerns in accordance to MVVM design pattern while connecting to a serial port?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm quite new to WPF and MVVM and I'm having trouble figuring out how the separation between the Model and the ViewModel should be implemented (Or should it exist at all.)

My education about WPF and MVVM mostly comes from [this tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZxZswmC_BY&list=PLA8ZIAm2I03hS41Fy4vFpRw8AdYNBXmNm) so admittedly I must be missing something.

I'm creating an application that would connect to a serial port and then communicated with it by sending and receiving data.

For now I'm building the connect interface. So I have my XMAL view and a ViewModel class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` to which some controls in the view are bound.

While the actual serial port class is the 'model'.

Currently what I do is have a field in the ViewModel for the SerialPort and a RelayCommand that's bound to a 'connect' button on the UI which initializes the connection.

This works, but it feels wrong, because as far as I understand it, the ViewModel shouldn't know about the SerialPort or anything else to do with the business logic.

But I'm at a loss as to how my design should be different. Should I fire a event in the view model when the button is clicked and the model (in this case the Serial port) should subscribe to this event and try to connect when the event is invoked?

This is my view model, though currently I just initiate the serial port as a local variable instead of a field for testing purpeses.

```
public class ConnectViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private static readonly int[] _baudRates = { 110, 300, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200 };

        private List<string>? _portNames;

        private int? _selectedBaudRate = null;

        private string? _selectedPortName = null;

        public ConnectViewModel(List<string>? portNames)
        {
            if (portNames == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(portNames));
            }
            PortNames = portNames;

            ConnectCommand = new RelayCommand(
                async () =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Connect Command Clicked. Selected Port:{SelectedPortName}, Selected BaudRate: {SelectedBaudRate}");
                    await ConnectToSerial();
                }
                //() => { return SelectedBaudRate != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedPortName); }
                );
        }

        public ICommand ConnectCommand { get; }

        private async Task ConnectToSerial()
        {
            if (SelectedBaudRate == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedPortName))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Selected Baudrate is none!");
                return;
            }
            int selectedBaudRate = (int)SelectedBaudRate;

            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort(portName: SelectedPortName,
                baudRate: selectedBaudRate, parity: Parity.None, stopBits: StopBits.One, handshake: Handshake.None, dataBits: 8);

            mySerialPort.OnConnectionStatusChanged += new ConnectionStatusChangedDelegate(
                (object sender, ConnectionStatus connectionStatus, string message) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(message);
                        if (connectionStatus == ConnectionStatus.Connected)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Succesfully connected!");
                        };
                    }
                );

            await mySerialPort.Connect();
        }
```

So my question is, is my current design legitimate? And how can I change my design to better separate concerns?

Comment: If you don't want the ViewModel to be responsible the serial port, then delegate the serial port functionality to another class.

Comment: You'd usually define a class does ghd serialport stuff. Abstract using an interface. Use di to inject the implementation to the viewmodel. Or pub sub pattern. A singleton and decouple using something like mvvm toolkit messenger.

Comment: @Andy I'm sure what you're saying makes sense to someone with a bit more experience than me at MVVM, but I would defiantly require some elaboration to understand it.

Comment: In a properly designed application you would hide all the details from the View Model. View Model would only implicitly connect to an anonymous client or data source. Usually via an interface. Then behind this interface the Model decides or knows how to connect and what kind of connection to use. You would hide the details like serial port from the View Model. Ideally the View Model would call Connect(params) on a Model type like e.g. IDataConnector. This way you totally decouple the business logic from the View Model as now the Model can change those details without breaking the View Model.

Comment: Such a Connect() method could be async instead of using events to communicate the status connected.

Comment: Of course, if your UI exposes multiple types of connections, then the View Model would get more awareness. But still you could express such connection types via an Enum that you pass to a single method. So again the Model alone decides how to handle the Enum values and would open a corresponding connection. View Model would know nothing about it. Neither the available connection types nor how to interpret the Enum parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad as you are asking for a design decision, which would usually require application details in order to make relevant suggestions.

In general, you would always try to decouple the View Model from the Model as much as possible. Given the basic application design or application architecture which is dictated by the MVVM pattern, you would additionally try to hide all the business details from the View Model. Ideally the View Model only depends on module abstractions.

Given is an example application that is supposed to send user data to a device via the serial port.
You can implement a View Model that is totally unaware of any details about how the business logic is actually working. The Model would expose an abstracted API that the View Model will use to read/write user data from/to the Model.

For the example application this could mean that the Model only exposes an interface that exposes a `WriteData` method. This way the View Model does not know how the data is actually written and to what kind of data sink the data is actually written to. This enables extensibility as you could change the business logic to use e.g. TCP to send data to the device without breaking the View Model.
The coupling becomes tighter if the user is allowed to control the behavior of the application for example by modifying application settings like setting a baud rate. In such a scenario changing the data pipe from serial port to TCP would break the View Model of course the View.

And because the Model has no dependency on the View Model, the Model would never be allowed to listen t o events of the View Model to start an operation.

Another big advantage from moving the actual details of the used connection to write data to a data sink from View Model to the Model is that now the Model is in full control over the lifetime of the connection object. This are all details that the View Model should not be aware of. The Model chooses the appropriate connection type and manages the connection. The connection is either part of the business logic or application's persistence layer. However, the Model must control it and hide all related details from the API:

**View Model**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IConfigurator
{
  public int BaudRate
  {
    get => this.baudRate;
    set
    {
      this.baudRate = value;

      // Use a model that handles i.e. persists application settings.
      // It will expect an IConfigurator with a 'BaudRate' property.
      // The value could then be written to a JSON file or data base.
      this.ApplicationSettings.WriteSettings(this as IConfigurator);
    }
  }

  public string TextData { get; set; }
  public ICommand SendDataCommand { get; }

  // Model
  private IApplicationSettings ApplicationSettings { get; }

  // Model
  private IDataWriter DataWriter { get; }

  private async Task ExecuteSendDataCommandAsync(object commandParameter)
  {
    // Write data using an anonymous technology
    await this.DataWriter.WriteAsync(this.TextData);
  }
}
```

**Model**

```cs
class DataWriter : IDataWriter 
{
  private IApplicationSettings ApplicationSettings { get; }

  // API hides all internal details from the caller.
  // The caller only knows the required data format but not how the data is handled.
  // Even the data format can change internally e.g. to adapt it to a protocol.
  public Task WriteAsync(string data)
  {
    SerialPortOptions serialPortOptions = this.ApplicationSetting.ReadSerialPortConfiguration();

    // You can further abstract the reference to the actual technology used to write data if required
    var serialPort = new SerialPort();
    await serialPort.ConnectAsync(serialPortOptions);
    await serialPort.SendAsync(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your explanation! I have a few questions though. Should `WriteAsync` create a new `SerialPort` instance every time a write occurs? Also shouldn't the SerialPort class be on a different thread? Or is the `Task.Run` handling allocation of task to new threads?

Comment: *"Should WriteAsync create a new SerialPort instance every time a write occurs?"* - It depends on how your SerialPort class works and how frequently you use it. If it is used rarely you may want to free resources and dispose the instance after use.

Comment: *"Also shouldn't the SerialPort class be on a different thread?"* - It also depends on how your SerialPort class is implemented. The general rule is that IO work should not be executed ona background thread as the performance is basically depending on the IO device. Modern APIs would expose naturally asynchronous members. Do async/await would be the way to go if supported. *"Or is the Task.Run handling allocation of task to new threads?"* - `Task.Run`will always create a background thread to execute the Action delegate on.